# Ubuntu への pip の導入は、どの選択が良いでしょうか？ apt or get-pip.py

Tags: python3, ubuntu, pip

Ubuntu 20.04 + Python3 にて、 pip を導入する方法の違いが理解できず、困っております。

Ubuntu上で pip を導入する場合には、apt を利用する or get-pip.py を利用するの、どちらが良いでしょうか？

最終的には、Rundeck の WinRM Node Executor を利用したく pywinrm の導入を行おうとしていました。

### apt を利用

インストールコマンド :

- `sudo apt install python3-pip`
- インストール先 : /usr/bin/pip3

パッケージ導入先：

- `apt` で入れたもの：

  - /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/
- `sudo pip3 install` で入れたもの：

  - /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages
- `pip3 install` で入れたもの：

  - /home/username/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages

上記のように設定したところ、コンソールで python CLI を使う場合、いずれの方法でいれたパッケージも利用できました。

しかし Rundeck の WinRM Node Executor からは apt でいれた pywinrm (python3-winrm) 以外は、利用が出来ませんでした。

3番目の .local 配下はともかく /usr/local/lib/ 配下のパッケージも利用出来ないのが何故かが、わかりません。

Ubuntuで pip を使うときには、apt を使わず、次の get-pip.py を使った導入を行うのが良いのでしょうか？公式に Ubuntuが管理しているのであれば、そちらから試すべきと思って各種試したのですが、納得の行く情報がつかめず。

お知恵を拝借できれば幸いです。

### get-pip.py を利用(案)

インストールコマンド :

- `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py`
- `python3 get-pip.py`

参考 : https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Answer (score 1):

参照している [インストールガイド](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing) の冒頭で、Unix (Linux) の場合には以下のような注意書きがあります。

> **Warning**
>
> If you installed Python from a package manager on Linux, you should always install pip for that Python installation using the same source.

利用している Python が OS のパッケージマネージャーを通してインストールしたものであれば、pip も同じ提供元 (=パッケージマネージャー、今回の例なら `apt`) を通じてインストールしてください。

---

"get-pip.py" でのインストールは、ディストリビューションのパッケージマネージャーに pip が存在しない、もしくはソースコード等から独自に Python をインストールした場合などに利用すればよいのだと思います。

Comment: cubickさん、 ありがとうございます！　なるほど、たしかに pip のインストールガイドに記載がありますね。この場合なのですが sudo pip3 install で導入したパッケージをグローバル？（今回の場合、具体的には rundeck から）使う方法を御存知でしたら、ご教授いただけると助かります。

自分のユーザーで python CLI から使う分には大丈夫なのですが、rundeckから（プロセスは rundeckユーザーで起動） からは該当パッケージが利用できない状態です。